# When deploying a Go 1.19 image with ECS, I get task faild to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, amazon-ecs

The ECS environment is

- Using ECS with EC2
- Using AutoScaling on EC2 with a capacity provider

This DockerFile is ECR deployed and used in ECS deployments.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.19.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY ../../. .

RUN go mod download
RUN make build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["make", "run"]
```

In that case, deploying to ECR is no problem, but when deploying to ECS, I get "Task failed to start".

Here is the content of the make command.

**Makefile**

```
BINDIR        := bin
NAME          := test_deploy
ENV_AWS       := aws
AWS_BINFILE   := $(NAME)_$(ENV_AWS)
REVISION      := $(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null || cat REVISION)
MAIN_FILE     := cmd/deploy/deployServerMain.go
GO            := go
GO_BUILD      := $(GO) build


build:
    CGO_ENABLE=0 $(GO_BUILD) -trimpath -ldflags '-s -w -X main.revision=${REVISION}' -o $(BINDIR)/$(AWS_BINFILE) $(MAIN_FILE)

run:
    ./$(BINDIR)/$(AWS_BINFILE)
```

The contents of deployServerMain.go are here.

**deployServerMain.go**

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8080"))
}
```

Checking the logs of failed deployments in ECS, it appears that the Echo server is starting up and then failing due to process-related issues.

**ECS Deploy Log**

```
2023/7/13 16:22:52 JST make: *** [Makefile:14: run] Terminated
2023/7/13 16:22:52 JST make: *** wait: No child processes.
2023/7/13 16:22:51 JST ____ __
2023/7/13 16:22:51 JST / __/___/ / ___
2023/7/13 16:22:51 JST / _// __/ __/ __ \/ __ \ 
2023/7/13 16:22:51 JST /___/\___/_/_/_/\___/ v4.10.0    
2023/7/13 16:22:51 JST High performance, minimalist Go web framework    
2023/7/13 16:22:51 JST https://echo.labstack.com    
2023/7/13 16:22:51 JST ____________________________________O/_______    
2023/7/13 16:22:51 JST O\   
2023/7/13 16:22:51 JST ⇨ http server started on [::]:8080   
2023/7/13 16:22:51 JST . /bin/test_deploy_aws
```

The first time I got this error I thought it might be a problem on the Go side, so I used the same Docker in my local environment and locally to make sure it worked.
At that time the server was up and running, no process errors, etc.

**Local**

```
➤ go version
go version go1.19.9 darwin/arm64
➤ make build
CGO_ENABLE=0 go build -trimpath -ldflags '-s -w -X main.revision=3507075' -o bin/test_dev_aws cmd/deploy/deployServerMain.go
➤ make run
./bin/test_dev_aws

   ____    __
  / __/___/ /  ___
 / _// __/ _ \/ _ \
/___/\__/_//_/\___/ v4.10.0
High performance, minimalist Go web framework
https://echo.labstack.com
____________________________________O/_______
                                    O\
⇨ http server started on [::]:8080
```

**Local Docker**

```
➤ docker compose up
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network ecs_test_default       Created                                                                                                                                         0.1s 
 ✔ Container ecs_test-libra-go-1  Created                                                                                                                                         1.2s 
Attaching to ecs_test-libra-go-1
ecs_test-libra-go-1  | ./bin/test_dev_aws
ecs_test-libra-go-1  | 
ecs_test-libra-go-1  |    ____    __
ecs_test-libra-go-1  |   / __/___/ /  ___
ecs_test-libra-go-1  |  / _// __/ _ \/ _ \
ecs_test-libra-go-1  | /___/\__/_//_/\___/ v4.10.0
ecs_test-libra-go-1  | High performance, minimalist Go web framework
ecs_test-libra-go-1  | https://echo.labstack.com
ecs_test-libra-go-1  | ____________________________________O/_______
ecs_test-libra-go-1  |                                     O\
ecs_test-libra-go-1  | 
ecs_test-libra-go-1  | ⇨ http server started on [::]:8080

➤ docker compose exec libra-go bash
root@1c3536fac65f:/app# go version
go version go1.19.1 linux/arm64
```

My guess is that the problem is caused by Autoscaling in ECS.
However, since this is my first time using ECS, I could not identify the problem in detail.
If anyone can solve the problem, please respond.

If there is any other information you need, please describe it in comments.

Comment: How are you deploying to ecs?